# Copy and paste to variable worksheet and range

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I want to copy and paste a range from a fixed worksheet ("c4:c178") into a variable worksheet.

I have two dropdowns, one has a list of all the worksheet names and the other has the column number.

My hope is the user could select the worksheet name and column reference in the drop-down and then click the macro button to copy and paste the range to that reference.

```vb
Sub CopyPaste()
    Dim Sheetname As String
    Sheetname = ActiveSheet.Range("i3").Value
    Dim Col As Long
    Col = ActiveSheet.Range("i4").Value
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tracking Only")
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("c4:C178")
    With rng
        ws.Cells(4, Col).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

I receive

> "Run-time error '1004': Application-define or object-defined error"

It highlights the ws.cells code.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Have you researched it and/or tried any code yet?

Comment: I did. I was able to copy and paste into a fixed range on a fixed sheet but couldn't figure out how to make the range variable, based on the contents of a cell. I am guessing it is as simple as knowing the right terminology. If there are existing questions similar to this, I apologize but searched "VBA copy paste variable inputs" for hours and everything I found was about code to select a variable range. The range is fixed it's the output that will be variable

Comment: I added the current code but honestly have tried several iterations that all yielded pretty much the same result. I really appreciate your help. If I can figure this out, it will save one of our nurses a ton of time!

Comment: What row should the data be pasted in? (there's a specification for column, but not for row)

Comment: The data will always paste into row 4

Comment: First of all, why did you change `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)` to `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tracking Only")`? Is the "Tracking Only" sheet the one with the dropdowns?

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry, I thought that's what you meant by sheet name. Should I have left that as sheetname?

Comment: Try the edited code in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Break your process into steps, store the dropdown values using variables, and assign the `.Value` of the source range to the target range.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tracking Only")
    Dim sheetName As String
    sheetName = .Range("I3").Value 

    Dim col As Long
    col = .Range("I4").Value
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = .Range("C4:C178")
End With

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)

With rng
    ws.Cells(4, col).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: Ben, thank you SO much for taking to time to help me with this. I think I am messing up the renaming section. How do I rename the dropdowns? The first dropdown is in Cell i3, with the second in I4. Sorry to make you break it down barney style

Dim Sheetname As String
Sheetname = ActiveSheet.Range("i3").Value
Dim Col As Long
Col = ActiveSheet.Range("i4").Value
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tracking Only")
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("c4:C178")
With rng
    ws.Cells(4, Col).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
End With